# Signifiant difference in Speed of SQL with join, vs without?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, left-join

I'm using ADO in VB6 to access a table in a Microsoft access database that has approximately 320,000 records.

The following SQL (note no join) takes approximately 3 hundredths of a second to execute. The result being 492 records of the 320,000 in that table!

```
Select * 
From AvailabilityBlocks 
Where [Begin] > #02-Oct-2013 12:00:00 AM# AND 
      (AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 2 OR 
      AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 3 OR 
      AvailabilityBlocks.Type=4) 
AND ResourceID = 59 
ORDER By [Begin], [End]
```

However, the following SQL takes about 11 seconds to run. The result being 363 of the 320k records.

```
Select * 
From AvailabilityBlocks 
LEFT JOIN Location 
    ON Availabilityblocks.LocationID=Location.LocationID 
Where [Begin] > #02-Oct-2013 12:00:00 AM# AND 
         (AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 2 OR 
         AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 3 OR 
         AvailabilityBlocks.Type=4) AND 
     (SubType=3 and AvailableForSPs=True) AND 
     ResourceID = 59 
     ORDER By [Begin], [End]
```

There must be a logical simple explanation for this, am I missing something totally obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe the constraint on (SubType=3 and AvailableForSPs=True) in the first query? Anyway the two queries don't look functionally equivalent...

Comment: The "SubType=3 and AvailableForSPs=True" criteria is part of the joined table! (Locations)

Comment: Is both `Availabilityblocks.LocationID` and `Location.LocationID`indexed fields?

Comment: yes they are both indexed.....I noted when I remove the criteria portion of the joined table (ie: SubType=3 and AvailableForSPs=True) the SQL (Which is still joined), runs as fast as the original, so now, I know the cause, but still do not have a solution!

Comment: What solution do you need? Currently, you give us 2 different SQL statements. We don't know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

For as far as I know a LEFT JOIN is slower than an INNER JOIN. Do you need the LEFT JOIN? In other words are there any nulls in you keys?

Comment: The difference between an LEFt and an INNER Join type is marginal, yes the inner is faster, but it still takes about 9 seconds to run vs 3 hundreths with the join!

Comment: Is your foreign key indexed?

Comment: yes it is....To restate what I commented above, the slowdown only happens when I put a condition on the joined table!